# Android: EditText maxLength being ignored

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a problem where this EditText ignores my maxLength completely.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="@color/primary_lighter"
        android:textColor="@color/accent_harder"
        android:hint="****"
        />
```

[image: maxLength is ignored]

I can input how many characters I want.

This is a dialog and I cannot get the EditText by findViewById because its available programtaically when I press OK.

```
public void showNewQuestionDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView( inflater.inflate( R.layout.dialog_question_new, null ) )
            .setPositiveButton( R.string.settings_ok, new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick( DialogInterface thisDialog, int id ) {
                    Dialog dialog2 = Dialog.class.cast( thisDialog );
                    EditText input = ( EditText ) dialog2.findViewById( R.id.dialog_input ); 

                    // Other code here..
                }
            } );
     .....
```

**I solved it.**
The problem was this line:

```
        android:singleLine="true"
```

If you ever experience the same problem, try removing this line.

Comment: Do you have a filter on this edit box? That property is done via a filter, and setting your own will remove Android's.  You'll need to implement the max chars yourself then.

Comment: @Jonas B if you accept the answer then you get more rep too. With 50 rep you get a new privilege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make sure that your XML attributes are not effecting another one.

It seems like these 2 could be the issue

```
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:singleLine="true"
```

---

I see you solved it already!  OK, the issue was...

```
    android:singleLine="true"
```

But you should double check to make sure that you cannot create a new line!

Comment: @Jonas B if you accept the answer then you get more rep too. With 50 rep you get a new privilege.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the underrated `LengthFilter`:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
int length = 4;
editText.setFilters(new android.text.InputFilter[] { new android.text.InputFilter.LengthFilter(length) });
```

Comment: Problem in my case was that the EditText couldnt be found unless I pressed any button, because it would give me an NullPointerException because it searches for the edittext before it was even created.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove below line in your layout to solve this problem

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Apart from that, you can always inflate the EditText dynamically with custom view like below 
and you can register for textwatcher in input mode.

```
LayoutInflator mInflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.dialog_question_new, null);
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
EditText input = ( EditText ) view.findViewById( R.id.dialog_input_question_new); 
mBuilder.setCustomTitle(view);
mBuilder.setPositiveButton(...
mBuilder.setPositiveButton(...
```