# EditText attribute maxLength not working properly/completely for letters

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout, android-edittext

Here is my EditText in xml layout:

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

**This EditText length limitation *(maxLength="2")* works just partially.**

It looks like user can't enter more than 2 characters because more is not shown, but in practise after pressing character *"A"* on keyboard 5 times he needs to press *"back"* (on keyboard) 4 times to delete second character and that makes no sense at all.

Funny enough this works correctly (as expected) with digits.

P.S. Already checked few question related questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774123/android-edittext-maxlength-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167171/android-edittext-maxlength-being-ignored-solved) but those solutions are not working

Comment: Not sure why I got negative here..? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically **auto-suggestion** on keyboard app is the source of messing this up, so characters need to be "deleted" even when they are not displayed. This doesn't happen with numbers because auto-suggestion can not really suggest something based on "23", no?

Anyways, solution is to add following attribute/value to your EditText:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

In theory you can combine this with other inputTypes, for example:

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
```

Hope I helped somebody facing this issue.. Enjoy programming ;)

Comment: just for records, I still find this weird so anyone who understands reasons behind it better feel free to advice or propose better solution